# Using WinAPI & DWMApi in ANSI C

Tags: c, winapi, c89, dwm

I've got a question regarding writing applications for Windows. Can I use WinAPI and DWMApi (aero glass, ribbon, etc.) when programming in ANSI C? I'm looking at MSDN right now and they use c++.

Comment: The C standards (either ANSI, or ISO99) does not countain most of the Windows API - which is not standardized. If you want a standard OS like API, consider using **POSIX** http://opengroup.org/ ; perhaps Microsoft sells something implementing a large part of Posix. So WinAPI is *not* part of any standard.

Comment: Can you post link to MSDN where WinAPI is exposed as C++?? I'm very interested cause never see it before.I coding with it few years...

Comment: Here's a ribbon article on MSDN which uses Cpp: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316924(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows API is a C API and can be used with any compiler that supports the 'standard' calling convention.

Microsoft has made the strategic decision to put their own C compiler on life support, though, and you're stuck with C90 (with some specific extension) when using Visual Studio. You can use 3rd party compilers (GCC and Clang via MinGW, Pelles C) which support more modern language dialects.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

Most APIs actually ARE C-APIs; they just call it C++ because "nobody" really uses C anymore. I've also noticed the occasional struct with additional functions attached to them, but definitely not in Win32, and they might just #ifdef that away for C.

The thing I don't know right away is whether the headers are "safe" when used with just C, and whether the libraries have unmangled symbols. I would assume they are, but one never knows. However, making a simple C program that just calls a single Win32 API function should clarify that.

Comment: I would only correct this to say that ALL (as opposed to most) Win32 apis are C-APIs, even the COM ones (and anyone that has had to write COM code using native C-only knows the pain, but reality, of that scenario). All the C++ toolkits with their class hierarchies, including MS's, are ultimately just wrappers around the bare metal: the WIN32 C-API.

Answer (score 0):

The Win32 API is accessible from many different toolsets. All C compilers for Windows that I have ever come across can call all Win32 APIs. What's more all these C compilers can call COM APIs and even GDI+ which is a very C++ centric library. But MS provided a bridge for C clients to use.

So, in summary, choosing to use C will not deprive you of access to any part of Win32.